# Override links in android webview

Tags: android

I could find no hint whatsoever on this topic. I wrote a simple app to load my website to a webView. The site contains many links and some of them are external. The webView is fine on browsing terms. But I want to be able to control what those links do. For example, use a particular link inside the webView to play a music file, for example. I have no code since i had nothing to try. I have the code for my app and webView but I dont see why that is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

set Webview client to your webview, you can get each clicked link on `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method with URL

```
YourWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebClientClass());
```

Here is your WebClientClass

```
public class WebClientClass extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, final String url) {
            // You have clicked link url here, do what you want here
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

adding to @Divyang answer

`shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url)` is deprecated in `Android N` so use below two methods

```
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    return true;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
    return true;
}
```